# Использование метода класса другим классом

Tags: java, классы, методы

Требуется, чтобы в одном классе был метод, который возвращал бы `List<String>`, а другой класс мог бы использовать этот класс.

Comment: сделайте метод статичным и используйте его когда захотите и где захотите. Всё в ваших силах

Answer (score 3):

```
public class OneClass{

 public static List<String> blabla(,,,){
 ////Ваша логика
 }
}

public class TwoClass{
 public yourMethod(..){
  List<String>,,,= OneClass.blabla(,,,);
 }
}
```